# sencha create jsb -a ./app.html -p ./app.jsb3

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In the Sencha SDK 3.0, sencha create is not a correct command!
When I enter

```
sencha create jsb -a ./app.html -p ./app.jsb3
```

I get info of "No such property : 'create'".

How can I create usb file in new Sencha SDK 3.0? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Type sencha without any parameters, let us know exactly what version info is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sencha create jsb
```

is a unique command and is ommitted from the Sencha Cmd v3.0 - why - who knows!?

you still need to use the SDK Tools v2.0, and this command (because`sencha` for v3.0 is in your path):

```
d:\_dev\ExtPackageTest>"C:\Program Files (x86)\SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3\sencha
" create jsb -a http://localhost:60139/index.html -p app.jsb3
```

Where `ExtPackageTest` is the root of your web app code

I think the best if you can move to Ext 4.1.3+ is to go straight to the new Sencha Cmd v3.0 for Ext Js follow this guide.

It's very sensitive and I'd recommend you create a new app with it and copy your app code into the template it generates. I found my code behaved differently after packaging into release mode and was told by support I'd "just got lucky" that this hadn't happened with the debug set up ^^.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error (`[ERR]           No such property : 'generate'`), but in other case - while trying to create my first app.
Instead of:
`sencha app create MyApp ../MyApp` 
I write: 
`sencha generate app MyApp ../MyApp`

Hope that's help